# Laravel Select Box

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to figure out how I can structure my Laravel select menu so that it shows up as this for a final render. Has anyone done such a thing.

The location is a property of the arena object.

```
<option value="arena_id">Arena Name - Location</option>

{{ Form::select('arena_id', [ null => 'Please Select'] + $arenas, null, ['id' => 'arena_id']) }}
```

Comment: What does `$arenas` look like?

Comment: I tend to use a view composer that grabs the data from the database, and prepend the default “Select:” `<option>` when binding it to the view.

Comment: Martin Bean do you have an example that you could put inside an answer for me to see what you are doing?

Answer (score 2):

I asssume `$arenas` comes from something like `Arena::where('foo', bar)->get()`, but with `get()` you will get an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instead of an actual array which is what you want in `Form::select`.

So what you need to do is to use `lists($field, $key)`, it will fetch you rows and return it as an array.

```
$arenas = Arena::where('foo', bar)->lists('name', 'id');
```

There is a code example [here](http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/easy-dropdowns-with-eloquents-lists-method) with some comments from users if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pluck function for getting the results as array

refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-pluck

```
$select = $this->all()->pluck('title', 'id');
```

Then you can use below sample code for creating select box with selected option in blade template

```
{{ Form::select('name',$select,'selected option id',['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```